# Jenkins: How to setup ignore paths for change polling for pipeline job?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Unable to get change polling to work while ignoring certain paths in the repo. I'm using the "Polling ignores commits in certain paths" feature in the pipeline config section. I tied setting "Included Regions" with paths I want to trigger a build. For example:

```
 asX/supervisor/.*
```

But, that doesn't work. I get various different failure modes.

1. fails to use updated config: i actually first set the path to asX/superviaor/** and the poll log showed an error that ** is invalid syntax. OK. So, I changed it to .*, and ran poll now. I got the same error about ** so it wasn't using updated config. But, I tried it again a few minutes later and no error about ** so it clearly updated a cache somewhere. So, that problem is temporary.
2. Sometimes I get error that git failed, and to fix that I have to delete the job dir NG-backend-check-3-script.

> error: unable to write file
> .git/objects/pack/pack-07c1ac57d393d4f91ec596575d56f7690f54734a.pack:
> Permission denied fatal: cannot store pack file fatal: index-pack
> failed

3. Sometimes the build would run every time I polled; always finding changes.

#1 and #2 seem to be bugs in Jenkins and I have workarounds. #3 is the worst since trying to make a job run less often results in it running more often!

I did try clearing included regions and set "Excluded Regions" with what I don't want to trigger build:

```
 BuildSystem/.*
 asX/algo/.*
 asX/embedded/.*
```

Same errors happen. Am I doing something wrong? Or is Jenkins just broken?

Jenkins 2.263.3

Comment: I've been searching for solution on this feature(polling ignores commits in certain paths)  and it seems to be a bug for sometime. I don't think it has been resolved. I am using github for code repository.